# Webpack2 BIG bundle file

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

```
bundle.js  2.81 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
  [13] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMComponentTree.js 6.16 kB {0} [built]
  [15] ./~/fbjs/lib/ExecutionEnvironment.js 1.06 kB {0} [built]
  [64] ./~/react/lib/React.js 2.69 kB {0} [built]
  [90] ./~/react/react.js 56 bytes {0} [built]
 [194] ./src/client/app/containers/Index/index.jsx 2.07 kB {0} [built]
 [195] ./~/react-dom/index.js 59 bytes {0} [built]
 [197] ./~/babel-polyfill/lib/index.js 833 bytes {0} [built]
 [406] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactDOM.js 5.14 kB {0} [built]
 [438] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactVersion.js 350 bytes {0} [built]
 [455] ./~/react-dom/lib/findDOMNode.js 2.46 kB {0} [built]
 [463] ./~/react-dom/lib/renderSubtreeIntoContainer.js 422 bytes {0} [built]
 [466] ./~/react/lib/ReactChildren.js 6.19 kB {0} [built]
 [467] ./~/react/lib/ReactClass.js 26.5 kB {0} [built]
 [468] ./~/react/lib/ReactDOMFactories.js 5.53 kB {0} [built]
 [476] ./src/client/app/private.jsx 210 bytes {0} [built]
    + 462 hidden modules
```

This is TOO big. Here are my configs.

.babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "es2015",
      {
        "modules": false
      }
    ],
    "es2016",
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-react-jsx",
    "transform-regenerator"
  ]
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
'use strict';

const path = require('path');

module.exports = [
  {
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    entry: './src/client/app/private.jsx',
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/private'),
      filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.jsx$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'babel-loader'
            },
          ],
          exclude: /node_modules/
        }
      ]
    }
  }
];
```

Now, I've looked in the file and a lot of it is commenting, so I presume it bundles it into a development bundle.

I've set the source map to inline, how does one test a production bundle?

Comment: If bundle size is the only concern, why not just add a minifier?

Answer (score 0):

For production, you will probably want source maps which are neither included nor referenced, so go with `hidden-source-map`.

If you're capturing and reporting runtime exceptions from clients, you can now use additional tools with the appropriate source maps provided to debug errors.